# Gitlab pipeline cannot build image from Dockerfile, package.json not found

Tags: docker, gitlab, devops

I'm trying to replicate the image build from a Dockerfile in the Gitlab pipeline. When i use docker locally in my machine I have no problem. But when I try to replicate the process in the pipeline, the script fails with the following error:

```
 Step 6/12 : RUN npm run-script build
 ---> Running in 4717c4b9d61a
 npm ERR! code ENOENT
 npm ERR! syscall open
 npm ERR! path /app/package.json
 npm ERR! errno -2
 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:18.09.7
services:
- docker:18.09.7-dind

stages:
- build
- test

variables:
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE -f ./hackapp/Dockerfile
before_script:
  - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CI_REGISTRY"
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG

test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - mongo:bionic
  script:
    - docker pull $IMAGE_TAG
    - docker run $IAMGE_TAG
```

And my Dockerfile

```
# Stage I

FROM node:stretch-slim AS react-build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app/

RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g
RUN npm run-script build

# Stage II
#Setup Nginx
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

#Fire up Nginx
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I tried installing adding `npm install npm@latest -g` in the first `RUN` but is like it cannot found the path to `package.json` file

Comment: Before `npm install`,try to do `npm init`, which will create your missing package.json.

Comment: I tried with it befor and after `npm install` and it didn't work. Also, if I'm providing the `package.json` , shouldn't the script take that file?

Comment: I got the same error just last week. It worked after doing this. May the copy really dint copy the package.json. Can you please RUN ls -l and check ??

Comment: Thanks, it was in fact a mistake in the route when copying files, since I made a change to do some testing

Comment: Np. I will just post the same as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the package.json is not really getting copied into /app/ directory. You can check using ls -l to be sure.